# Passing arguments from Visio ShapeSheet to procedure in VBA

Tags: vba, parameter-passing, procedure, shapes, visio

I have been working with Visio VBA for a couple of years. I pass arguments from the ShapeSheet of a shape to several procedures in VBA using either RUNMACRO() or CALLTHIS() Functions.

I either pass pass plain strings or the value of different formulas in the ShapeSheet. The most common argument that I pass to my procedures is the ID() of the shape.

After a patch update of Windows: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/march-15-2021-kb5001566-os-build-18363-1441-out-of-band-23c4c824-8638-43e9-a381-ff58213ae6fe, I am no longer able to pass arguments from the ShapeSheet of a Shape to my procedures in VBA. Whenever I use RUNMACRO or CALLTHIS, all the arguments that I pass, even if they are plain strings, in my procedure side everything that I get is "", blank information.

Is there a way to know if this is a bug or if this is on purpose, maybe as a security measure?

Here is a simple example procedure:

```vb
Public Function HelloWorld(Number As Integer)
    
    If Number = 1 Then
      MsgBox ("Hello World 1")
    End If
    
    If Number = 2 Then
      MsgBox ("Hello World 2")
    End If

End Function
```

And this procedure is called in the EventDblClick of a Shape:

```
RUNMACRO("HelloWorld(1)","Test")
```

When the EventDblClick is triggered the value of Number stays as null, ignoring the argument sent in the RUNMACRO function, which is a 1. Since the argument of Number in the HelloWorld() function is not optional, it triggers a Compile error message

> "Argument not optional"

Comment: Including your code in the post would help readers eliminate a number of possibilities. Please [edit] your post to show us exactly how your code is passing these parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, already added an example code.

Answer (score 0):

My programs were also recently affected by this update.  Previously, I was able to structure the ‘macroname’ string in RUNMACRO (macroname [,projname_opt]) to include arguments to my functions and subroutines (as in Alexis’ HelloWorld example).  However, that suddenly seems to be no longer possible.  It is almost as if RUNMACRO is now modifying the ‘macroname’ string to exclude any arguments prior to making the call to the Function or Subroutine.

One workaround that I have found is to use CALLTHIS and restructure the VBA Function or Subroutine slightly as shown below.  That said, it is going to be a huge hassle for me to execute this change in every cell, in every shape, in every file using the RUNMACRO formula.  I’m going to have to write a separate macro just to execute this change.

Workaround:

CALLTHIS(HelloWorld,,1)
[NOTE: The two commas are intentional.]

```
Public Function HelloWorld(callingShape as Visio.Shape, number as Integer)
       ‘Insert Code Here
End Function
```